# FOR Loop with multiple parameters from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, lubridate

I would like to know whether it is possible to build a FOR loop in R which would change multiple parameters at every run.

I have parameter dataframe [df_params] which looks like this:

```
group   person   date_from             date_to
1        Mike    2020-10-01 12:00:00   2020-10-01 13:00:00
2        Mike    2020-10-04 09:00:00   2020-10-07 17:00:00
3        Dave    2020-10-07 12:00:00   2020-10-07 13:00:00
4        Dave    2020-10-09 09:00:00   2020-10-11 17:00:00
```

I would like to loop over a larger dataframe [df] and get only the rows matching parameters of individual rows in the "df_params" dataframe.

The large dataframe [df] looks like this:

```
person    datetime              books  tasks  done
Mike      2020-10-01 12:15:00   5      7      2 
Mike      2020-10-01 12:17:00   5      7      3 
Mike      2020-10-01 18:00:00   5      7      4 
Mike      2020-10-02 12:00:00   5      5      0 
Mike      2020-10-04 09:08:00   5      3      3 
Mike      2020-10-09 12:00:00   5      7      1 
Dave      2020-10-07 12:22:00   7      5      1 
Dave      2020-10-08 02:34:00   7      5      2 
Dave      2020-10-09 07:00:00   7      3      3 
Dave      2020-10-09 08:00:00   7      8      5 
Dave      2020-10-09 09:48:00   7      7      2 
Nick      2020-10-01 13:00:00   3      7      3 
Nick      2020-10-02 12:58:00   3      3      2 
Nick      2020-10-03 10:02:00   3      7      1
```

The desired result would look like this:

```
person    datetime              books  tasks  done   group
Mike      2020-10-01 12:15:00   5      7      2      1
Mike      2020-10-01 12:17:00   5      7      3      1
Mike      2020-10-04 09:08:00   5      3      3      2
Dave      2020-10-07 12:22:00   7      5      1      3
Dave      2020-10-09 09:48:00   7      7      2      4
```

Is something like this possible in R.
Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes you can get individual rows that match certain criteria in your parameters. are you needing to create a new column in the df based on certain values for individuals?

Comment: Hi, I need to create a new dataframe containing only the selected rows.

Comment: Okay, yes. Sounds like you want to do a `merge()` or a `union()` which are database type functions where you take 2 datasets and *join* them based on matching criteria. What criteria are you needing to match on the rows? Then you tell the function how you want it to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a slightly expensive solution if your datasets are very large, but it outputs the desired result.

I don't know if your date variables are already in date format; below I convert them with the `lubridate` package just in case they aren't.
Also, I create the variable `date_interval` that will be used later for a filtering condition.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# convert to date format
df_params <- df_params %>% 
  mutate(
    date_from = ymd_hms(date_from),
    date_to = ymd_hms(date_to),
    # create interval
    date_interval = interval(date_from, date_to)
    )

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime))
```

After this manipulation step, I use a `left_join` on the person name in order to have a larger dataframe - for this reason I said before that this operation might be a little expensive - and then `filter` only the rows where `datetime` is *within* the above-mentioned interval.

```
left_join(df, df_params, by = "person") %>% 
  filter(datetime %within% date_interval) %>% 
  select(person:group)
#   person            datetime books tasks done group
# 1   Mike 2020-10-01 12:15:00     5     7    2     1
# 2   Mike 2020-10-01 12:17:00     5     7    3     1
# 3   Mike 2020-10-04 09:08:00     5     3    3     2
# 4   Dave 2020-10-07 12:22:00     7     5    1     3
# 5   Dave 2020-10-09 09:48:00     7     7    2     4
```

---

**Starting data**

```
df_params <- read.table(text="
group    person  date_from             date_to
1        Mike    2020-10-01T12:00:00   2020-10-01T13:00:00
2        Mike    2020-10-04T09:00:00   2020-10-07T17:00:00
3        Dave    2020-10-07T12:00:00   2020-10-07T13:00:00
4        Dave    2020-10-09T09:00:00   2020-10-11T17:00:00", header=T)

df <- read.table(text="
person    datetime              books  tasks  done
Mike      2020-10-01T12:15:00   5      7      2 
Mike      2020-10-01T12:17:00   5      7      3 
Mike      2020-10-01T18:00:00   5      7      4 
Mike      2020-10-02T12:00:00   5      5      0 
Mike      2020-10-04T09:08:00   5      3      3 
Mike      2020-10-09T12:00:00   5      7      1 
Dave      2020-10-07T12:22:00   7      5      1 
Dave      2020-10-08T02:34:00   7      5      2 
Dave      2020-10-09T07:00:00   7      3      3 
Dave      2020-10-09T08:00:00   7      8      5 
Dave      2020-10-09T09:48:00   7      7      2 
Nick      2020-10-01T13:00:00   3      7      3 
Nick      2020-10-02T12:58:00   3      3      2 
Nick      2020-10-03T10:02:00   3      7      1 ", header=T)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It works great!